# Customizing mat-checkbox

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I would like to change the angular material mat-checkbox checked icon. By default, the check icon is a white tick icon shown in a colored background box. What I need is a cross instead of tick (single problem, just show cross instead of tick when it is checked). The whole day searching, could not find a proper solution for that. Would be really appreciated for any ideas with sample codes. I am using Angular 10 and scss styling.

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BISLe.jpg)

Comment: Please **reopen** the question. It is focused on one single problem, i.e., changing tick icon with cross icon. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You can replace checkbox's default svg with any svg here.
Just you have to manipulate you dom.

Here is the minimal working example you can achieve
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyg5sz?file=src/app/checkbox-configurable-example.ts)

I have used `document` which is not recommended to manipulate dom in Angular.

You can check other methods for eg. `renderer2`, `hostbinding`, etc.